# Rails helper method execution before call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, helpermethods

The `@test` variable I have is getting evaluated before I want it to. Here's what I intend: I have a button (link right now) with a variable shown next to it. The value should say "blank" when the page is initially loaded. When I click that button, the page should refresh and the variable should be changed to something else because the button calls a helper method.

Here's what I have in home.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Do stuff', my_helper_method(), :method => :get %>
<%= @test %>
```

Here's what I have in my_proj_helper.rb (helper method):

```
module MyProjHelper
    def my_helper_method()
       @test = "changed"
    end
end
```

In my_proj_controller.rb (controller), I have this:

```
class My_Proj_Controller < ApplicationController
    def home
        @test = "blank"
    end
end
```

I must not be doing things correctly. What needs to change?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a helper method like that. Here's what you can do:

Create a route in routes.rb

```
   get '/some_path/:test_variable' => 'my_proj_controller#test_action', as: :test_action
```

Then create a corresponding action in your controller

```
   def test_action
     @test = params[:test_variable]
     render 'home'
   end
```

Then change the link

```
    <%= link_to 'Link', test_action_path('change') %>
```

What it does when user clicks the link is it sends a GET request from your page to `My_Proj_Controller` with a `test_variable` parameter in it. 
Your controller receives the request, sets `@test` variable and renders the `home.html.erb` page then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to hit the helper method when you click.  This isn't what helper methods are for - they simply do something that you need in a view or controller - like render html.  The 'link_to' method is a helper, for example.  If you want the @test variable to change as you want - just set the value in the controller conditionally.

The second param of the link_to method is supposed to be the url that you are tring to navigate to.  If it's a method, it should return a string.  In this case, you call a method that does return a string.  If you look in the a href="" of that tag, you'll see "changed" as the href attribute.